# Cannot query XML document using XDocument and get desired results

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I'm trying to use the Bing maps API, which returns an XML document. The document (simplified but keeping structure) is

```
<Response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1">
    <StatusCode>
    200
    </StatusCode>
    <ResourceSets>
      <ResourceSet>
       <Resources>
        <TrafficIncident>
         <Severity>
          Minor
         </Severity>
         <RoadClosed>
          false
         </RoadClosed>
        </TrafficIncident>
       </Resources>
      </ResourceSet>
     </ResourceSets>
</Response>
```

In this case, there is only 1 traffic issue but there could be many.

I'm trying to extract if the road is closed and the severity

The XML is stored in a `xd` object (of type `XDocuement`)

The following works fine (no error but returns all the elements)

```
var allNodes = (from x in xd.Descendants()
                select x).ToList();
```

but if I add an element name then it returns a list with 0 items

```
var allNodes = (from x in xd.Descendants("Resources")
                select x).ToList();
```

I thought the above code is saying:

> from xd, grab all of the descendants of the "Resources" element

If my understanding is correct, why does it return 0 results

Comment: Just to clarify, is the root of `xd` the `Response` element?  i.e. you're not loading at a different element, right?

Comment: Also, I'm not able to test at the moment but try `xd.Descendants("//Resources")`

Comment: Hmm... as I said, unable to test at the moment.  There's some method which allows you to use XPath to query the document structure.  I can't think of it offhand.

Comment: No worries, but than you @Yuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must include your (default) XML namespace like so:

```
var name = XName.Get("Resources", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1");
var allNodes = (from x in xd.Descendants(name)
                select x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You must not forget the XML Namespace.

```
XNamespace search = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1";

var allNodes = (from x in xd.Descendants(search + "Resources")
                select x).ToList();
```

Comment: You should XName.Get() for that, see my answer.

Comment: The XNamespace class has operators to enable this (hopefully) nicer syntax. See [addition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.op_addition) and [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.op_implicit).

Comment: I'm more concerned about readability. But then again, that is always partly opinion.based.